# How to response instantaneously to the change of database in parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm developing an iOS and android app on parse. I'm a newbie

I want Mr.A to post into Mr.B database and then the device of Mr.B get the new data that has been posted by Mr.A instantaneously, Can I do this in parse? I have heard the push notification is slow and not match with this job. and the pulling interval is not a good practice.

I do not want Mr.B to refresh manually. I want it to happen automatically when Mr.A post into Mr.B

Can I use cloud code and make after save function? they push it to Mr.B device? (not push notification)

Comment: Parse isn't a good fit for what you are trying to do. You might want to checkout something like firebase.

Comment: Parse can't do this. The interfaces it supports for iPhone/Android/REST etc aren't push, and the connections are not streaming/websockets. Your only solutions are using (1) Push Notifications to indicate to Mr. B's device that there is new data to retrieve or (2) poll. Neither of these are nice solutions, but they're all that's available. I'd definitely recommend push over polling. It's not that slow (a few seconds), but you won't want to use to push live stock market data, or auction bits to a device :-)